# At which point does $F(x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t^{3/2}}dt,0<x<\infty$ has a local maxima value?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $F(x)=\int_0^{x}\frac{\sin(t)}{t^{3/2}}dt,0<x<\infty.$Then $F(x)$ local maxima value at the point-

$(1)\pi/2$

$(2)4\pi$

$(3)\pi$

$(4)2\pi$

I tried to first compute $F'(x)$ via Leibnitz's rule but due to the lower limit of the given integral it is not able to work...

Please give some hint

Comment: Here is a hint: The derivative of $F(x)$ should be computed by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 3):

This is a differentiable function in the open set $(0,+\infty)$. Therefore, the local maxima/minima will occur in points where $F'(x)=0$. In fact (this must be justified):
$$
F'(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x^{3/2}},
$$

which means that $F'$ vanishes in points of the form $x = n \pi, n \ge 1$. The local maxima will actually occur at $x = \pi + 2n \pi$ (the other stationary points lead to local minima). In terms of the available options, the answer would be $\pi$.